# How do I edit the label and x-axis of a laravel/chart.js boxplot?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, frontend, chart.js

Chart.js translation for plotting on frontend side in Laravel. There is a yield of 3 months dates and their datas. How should I fit charjs that overlap and not all dates are written at the end of x? (texts are overlapping, i dont want it, and I want all the dates to be on the x-axis, I think chartjs skipped it because couldn't fit it.) it is important can you contact with me

[image]

```
 var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
                labels: dates,
                datasets: [{
        label: 'BACKLOG ON HOLD INCIDENTS AVG PERFORMANCE- BURSA',
        data: results,
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(76, 196, 23, 0.6)'

        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(219, 249, 219, 1)',

        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
                }]
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        options: {

                plugins:{
                legend:{
                        display:true
                },
        datalabels:{
                color:'blue',
                anchor:'end',
        font:{
                weight:'bold',
                size:8
             }
                  }
        },
        scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true
           },
        x: {
            ticks: {
                maxRotation: 90,
                minRotation: 90,
                font: {
                size: 8,
            }
            }
           }
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        }
        }
    });
```